# How to get the posts of the news feed with graph api javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get my Facebook news feed in order to filter depending on some options.

But when I ask for permission as below, read_stream is not accepted, I 'm getting "Invalid Scopes: read_stream"

```
FB.login(checkLoginStatus, {scope:'read_stream,email,publish_actions, user_friends, user_posts  '});
```

Looking around in Internet, I found out that this permission has to be required from Facebook.

Any workaround for that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The permission `read_stream` was deprecated with v2.4. You wouldn't have gotten it granted during Login Review anyway.

Basically, `/{user_id}/home` endpoint with the newsfeed is no longer accessible. If you want to use `/{user_id}/feed`, that should work, but this only contains the user's own timeline.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/user/home/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/user/feed